# Font Files Resolution and conversion from pdf

Tags: adobe-illustrator, font-design

I have created a new font from a template I got from calligraphr.com. I am wondering firstly, what dpi I should save them at and secondly, if I can save them as a .pdf, then convert them to .fnt, .ttf, or whatever.

Comment: Why would dpi be on discussion when we are talking about a font?

Answer (score 1):

Your question needs guesses. Here are some:

- you have not created a font, you have only printed and filled their template form with your own letters. Or equivalently you have filled the blank form in a computer with a drawing program
- you are not sure should you scan the filled paper form or save the computer drawing to PDF or something else and with what resolution

I do not believe they accept PDFs because their example file is JPG. So scan your filled form to JPG with highest possible JPG quality level and be sure the image has is at least 1200 pixels high, preferably more. They seem to accept up to 7200 pixels high images. If you filled the form in a drawing program save it as highest possible quality JPG and be sure the resulted image is 1200...7200 pixels high. I bet they do not even read what is written to the metadata field about DPI, the number of pixels count.

Your scanner can want some DPI setting. If the form is A4, use 300...600 DPI.

Many office scanners save as PDF. If you cannot save as JPG because you have not the needed password, save as PDF and convert the image to JPG with Inkscape, Photoshop or Illustrator.

Nobody shoots if you try to upload a PDF. If you are lucky (and I guessed wrong) you soon get a download dialog for a TTF or OTF file. That file contains the font. You drew the glyphs of the font and maybe got also a possiblity to insert some metrics and variation information, if you are a pro customer of calligraphr.com.